# How to run a query with the values of a windows open PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have a calendar, when I click on a random day it appears another page with the days, months and years that I selected.

This is my code to appear in the other page

```
window.open("main.php?year="+yy+"&month="+mm+"&day="+dt)
```

My question is how can I run a query to mysql that uses that variables, "yy", "mm", "dt" in another page.

This is what I tried?

```
$sql = "
SELECT HoraIni
     , MinutoIni
     , HoraFim
     , MinutoFim
     , CdCurso
     , NmCurso
     , DgTpMarcacao 
  FROM marcacaosalas 
 Where Data = " "yy" - "mm" - "dt" "
 ";
```

I tried the $_Get suggestions but it cant retreive the variables with the $_get dont know why

```
    $day = $_GET['dt'];
$month = $_GET['mm'];
$year  = $_GET['yy'];
```

Comment: what's the format you are looking for

Comment: The variables that i wanna get i want it on a format in date, yyyy-mm-dd to be more specify

Comment: You shouldn't use `$_GET['mm'];` you should use `$_GET['month'];`

Comment: But i declared on the other page that i created that mm was month

Comment: No As I said in my answer you should use the part that is before the equal sign.

Comment: The error is in your query not the GET items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send data using GET method within your url you should update your query in main.php getting:

```
$day = $_GET['year'];
$month = $_GET['month'];
$year  = $_GET['day'];
$sql = "SELECT HoraIni,MinutoIni,HoraFim,MinutoFim,CdCurso,NmCurso,DgTpMarcacao FROM marcacaosalas Where Data ='$year-$month-$day'";
```

Anyway i dont understand why you don't easly send the whole data to the page simpli using a fomith a date input inside like:

```
<form method="get">
   <input type='date' name='date' />
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Nahh, i need to do on the $_get way, but im always getting an error on the sql query!

Comment: well, echo the query before submting to mysql so you can see what you are doing wrong. Is possible that you need to include the data value in single quote, i edit my answer below.

Comment: Thanks, i no longer have the query error, but it is not getting the variables on
$day = $_GET['yy'];
$month = $_GET['mm'];
$year  = $_GET['dt'];

i did echo and it doesnt appear me anything, what a strange thing :/

Comment: Probably they are null. Do var_dump($variable) instead of echo so you can see if u get something. Anyway i think you need to work by step: 1)you can try your query directly in mysql (or phpmyadmin) so you can see if it returns something. 2)When the query is ok try to build the correct string in php echoing that 3)try to execute from php script.

Comment: P.s. look in browser url if you see main.php?mm=something&dd=something and so on. Maybe you get some problems whith the javascript.If you send more code i can help you.

Comment: Dear Brother @SBO, the url that he is opening is `"main.php?year="+yy+"&month="+mm+"&day="+dt` That means that the $_GET array will contain `"year"` as a key not `yy` Hope this will emit a light beam on the error

Comment: <script language="javascript">
function post_value(mm,dt,yy){ 
 window.open("main.php?year="+yy+"&month="+mm+"&day="+dt);

This is what i have in other page, that it will open the page that i want and writting in the url

Comment: Oh yeah, i mean that. So, in main.php var_dump($_GET['year']), month and day and check if they are the value you need. When you are sure follow the 3 steps i wrote before, should find your problem.

Comment: @user3980820 i already tried with year, and it still has the same problem. i have my database full and when i "ask" with the mysql it doesnt appear me anything on the page

Comment: please copy the url in main.php

Comment: It's impossible that if you var_dump($_GET['year']) in main.php you get null!

Comment: Eheheh, programming is soooo imprevedible :-) remember to delete cache when you reload the page. In chrome you can use ctrl+f5 or in firefox disable in settings. Bye, have a good work!

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `$_GET` array to get these elements from URL

### How to use $_GET

you first pass the value that you want to get on the other webpage in the url like this `yourpage.php?indexofthevalue=value`

Where : `indexofthevalue` is the indicator that you are going to get the value with.

And you get that value by this code `$_GET[indexofthevalue]` and it will return the value

### Code

So now you'll get the year by this `$_GET["year"]` and so on

```
$year = $_GET["year"];
$day = $_GET["day"];
$month = $_GET["month"];
$sql = "SELECT HoraIni,MinutoIni,HoraFim,MinutoFim,CdCurso,NmCurso,DgTpMarcacao FROM marcacaosalas Where Data =STR_TO_DATE($year-$month-$day, '%Y-%m-%d')";
```

### PS

The GET method is not safe.

Comment: Thanks, but im still getting an error on the query, dont know why :/

Comment: Please can you expand on why it is unsafe, and why you suggest this method if it is not safe?

Comment: Because of sql injections. Without pdo which prepares statement and filter bad words inside it you can send to the server sql statements using the browser url. If you don't use pdo you can use some php native functions like htmlentities, stripslashes, mysq_real_escape_string() but all of this are deprecated.

Comment: I didn't sugfest it the OP used it

Comment: Im making this for internal purpose